# Concurrency with JMS

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, glassfish, jms

I've got a time consuming task which I'd like to speed up by dividing it into smaller chunks and processing those chunks simultaneously. As it's going to be EJB job running on Glassfish server I have to use JMS for that purpose (as long as I can imagine).
So I'm going to create 9 separate messages for every single request. That's an easy part. Those messages will be processed then by MDB, which onMessage method will recognize each particular part upon the payload header message element. 
The problem is I can't figure out how to collect and store the results until all of them will be ready to combine them into the response message. 
Or actually I can imagine the solution with the temp files but I don't think it's the best one. What is the best practice for that kind of job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JMS as described, one way to do it is to store temporary results in a database table and wait for all tasks to complete in order to combine results.

Instead, as long as your are using at least Java EE 6, you can use [asynchronous method invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html), which is the replacement for many usages of JMS within one container just for the purpose of doing something asynchronously. With this technique, as described in the tutorial, you can also retrieve the final results.

Comment: I don't have to stick to JMS at all, your second suggestion is what I actually need.